# jsPDF shwoing Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.text on nginx server

Tags: angular, jspdf

I have implemented jspdf my project admin.

everything works fine on localserver admin panel.

But as soon as I make it live on nginx server side throws this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.text
Error: Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.text
```

[image: screenshot of console of chrome]

it is breaking on below line of code:

```
  pdf.setFontSize(18);
  pdf.text('INVOICE', 550, col2y, {align:'right'});
```

All the above lines were not having `TextOptionsLight.align` so it passed. Here `{align:'right'}` is causing the error.

But as per documentation, it is perfectly alright. Even exactly the same code works in Frontend.

Comment: did you solve this

Comment: yes, I solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error and the code below work for me. Do this :

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
// your code
doc.text(100, 20, 'Your text', 'center');
```

Default is 'left', so either use 'center' or 'right'.

`100` and `20` are respectively `padding-left` and `padding-top` applying to your text

Documentation says you need to add an argument for the text angle before the alignment, but it works regardless

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/dist/jspdf+text+center